# USB MP3 player is not recognized by Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows-xp, usb, mp3-player

I have Windows XP SP3 and a USB MP3 player (some no-name brand).
USB flash drives are recognized properly on my computer, but my USB MP3 player is not.

Yesterday, the same MP3 player was recognized normally. There is no yellow question mark in device manager.

I've already tried with restarting, plugging in the lplayer again, without results.

Comment: Are all updates installed for Windows? Is the player compatible with the computer (USB specs or Windows XP)?

Comment: @slhck,  excuse me, I didn't say - yesterday the same mp3 player was recognized normally. I updated my post. I don't know what is the model of player. Nothing is written on it, except some numbers and capacity. I can't see it in anyway, including as removable drive.

Comment: Are there any drivers required for this device?

Comment: @bonaca: Does the MP3 player have an option to set USB mode? If you accidentally changed it to MTP mode I don't think it would work on XP by default, it needs to be set to MSC (mass storage class).

Comment: @root, I don't know, but I suppose , when I plug in the player, windows should tell if some drivers are missing. But there is no any sign that the device is plugged in at all. Also, device manager is without any yellow question mark. Now I tried system restore on yesterday's point - no help. USB stick drive is recognized normally.

Comment: @James, I'm sure I didn't change anything on player from yesterday, when it was recognized properly.